# elaboration error: mongodb-database-tools

Tags: linux, mongodb, postgresql, ubuntu, dpkg

i'm trying to install postgresql on my Linux Pc with `sudo apt-get -y install postgresql` 
but the terminal give me that output (i'm sry but is italian):

[image]

so i've tryed to install that with `sudo apt install mongodb-database-tools` but the terminal give back the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for installation

> To install PostgreSQL, first refresh your server’s local package index:

```
sudo apt update
```

> Then, install the Postgres package along with a -contrib package that adds some additional utilities and functionality:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

To make sure it's installed enter this command in the terminal `psql --version` and it will should output something like this

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1)
```